# how to find a lightbox / fancybox with Capybara

Tags: html, ruby, fancybox, cucumber, capybara

I have not found a clear answer to finding and manipulating elements within my fancybox modal laden webapp.

```
within("div#fancybox-wrap.fancybox-desktop.fancybox-type-iframe.fancybox-opened") do
    page.find_by_id('blah container').click
end
```

here is a bigger context as requested

```
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-iframe fancybox-opened" style="width: 415px; height: auto; display: block; position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 467px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible;">
<div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 15px;">
    <div class="fancybox-outer">
        <div class="fancybox-inner" style="width: 385px; height: 229px; overflow: hidden;">
            <iframe class="fancybox-iframe" name="fancybox-frame" frameborder="0" hspace="0" scrolling="auto" src="index.php?module=Yadda&amp;action=[where I wan to be]&amp;popup=Y&amp;id=[unique]&amp;width=1010&amp;height=600">
                [the stuff I want to access]
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
<div title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close">
```

this generates the following reject...

```
  Unable to find css "div#fancybox-wrap.fancybox-desktop.fancybox-type-iframe.fancybox-opened" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Is there anything I need to add/subtract?

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML of the page or a page that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css locator is incorrect.

Having

```
div#fancybox-wrap
```

means a div with id "fancybox-wrap". Based on the html, "fancybox-wrap" is a class. Therefore, you actually want (note the "#" changed to a "."):

```
within("div.fancybox-wrap.fancybox-desktop.fancybox-type-iframe.fancybox-opened") do
    page.find_by_id('blah container').click
end
```

Comment: I think that that did it.  Thanks Justin!

Answer (score 0):

Found a better answer that was inspired by this answer

[Temporarily set js_errors to false in Poltergeist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020680/temporarily-set-js-errors-to-false-in-poltergeist)

but will only work if you are using poltergist which is using capybara with phantomjs

```
# think about it. this is what you do in real life
# Try to click thing you actually want. get caught by the the overlay then click to dismiss it away
tried_before = false
  if page.has_css?('#autostart')
    begin
      click_link "Insurance", match: :first 
    rescue Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed
      # close the fancy box
      if tried_before
        raise e
      end 
      find('#fancybox-close').click
      retry
    end 
  end 
end
```

What does it do?

1. try to click the thing we actually wanted
2. if it cant now we know the overlay is in the way
3. we can click it now

Comment: Hacky `page.find('html').click` worked for me to close it.